# VerifyCsrfToken Exception on form submit after AJAX response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have AJAX action which renders a form which contains several input fields and submit button.

This is AJAX call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#call_filter').click(function() {
   $.ajax({
    url : 'brandSpendingsFilter',
    type: 'POST',

    data: {company: $('#company').val(), country: $('#country').val(), dateFrom: $('#dateFrom').val(), dateUntil: $('#dateUntil').val(), media: $('#media').val(),
    products: $('[id^=products_]').serialize()},

    beforeSend: function() {$('#search_result').empty(); $("#loading-image2").show(); },
    error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        console.log( errorThrown );
    },
    success : function(data) {
        $("#loading-image2").hide();
       $('#search_result').append(data);
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

And my form:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'brandSpendingsCSV', 'method' => 'POST', 'id' => 'csv']) !!}
{{ csrf_field() }}
<input type="hidden" name="campaignID" value="@foreach($campaignID as $c){{$c}},@endforeach">
<input type="hidden" name="dateFrom" value="{{$dateFrom}}">
<input type="hidden" name="dateUntil" value="{{$dateUntil}}">
<input type="hidden" name="media" value="{{$media}}">
<input type="hidden" name="country" value="{{$country}}">

</tr>
</table>
@if(Auth::user()->isAdmin())

<div class="row" style="float: right;"><button type="submit" onclick="submitForm()" class="btn btn-warning">CSV EXPORT</button></div>
@endif

<br>
<br>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

This onclick function is simple submit code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm(){
    $('#csv')[0].submit();
}
</script>
```

As you can see from the form code I have already included the csrf field. But still after this I am getting an error `VerifyCsrfException`.
Another thing that I have tried is to include AJAX headers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

But still error remains. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

I changed route type to GET and added this

```
<a href="brandSpendingsCSV?campaignID=@foreach($campaignID as $c){{$c}},@endforeach&dateFrom={{$dateFrom}}&dateUntil={{$dateUntil}}&media={{$media}}&country={{$country}}"><button class="btn btn-warning">CSV EXPORT</button></a>
```

It works at the moment, but I'll keep the question open since this is temporary solution. I need to have POST method.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the payload that is sent to the server, to confirm the token is being sent? Because it looks like you might have two things submitting above; a `filter` request then the actual `form` request, right? Perhaps the error is occurring during the filter request?

Comment: are you added `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` to head tag ?

Comment: @MortaddaJafar yes, I have.

Comment: @camelCase .. The csrf value isn't passed at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating token in page by usign `{{ csrf_field() }}`, so you can use as

```
 headers: {
   'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('input[name="_token"]').val()
 }
```

or add  an element named `_token` to post data

```
var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
data: {_token:_token,company: $('#company').val(),
```

Also calculate value `campaignID` before textbox or at the top of page

Answer (score 0):

Add to rest of data the token:

```
data: {
        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
      }
```

Cheers!

Comment: I've tried and it's not working. Also I tried this - `_token: $('#_token').val()` and added hidden field with `id= "_token"`

Answer (score 0):

With the jQuery serialize() method the token posted with all others form data.

```
data: $(this).serialize(),
```

Comment: Not working. Tried to add that to data field.. Also tried to add this: `_token: $(this).serialize()`